# Peterson algorithm in Java?

Tags: java, algorithm, concurrency, thread-safety, memory-model

Is there example implementation of Peterson algorithm for mutual exclusion in Java?

Comment: Please do not hesitate to post your own answers, I am looking for the best one!

Comment: Do you mean Peterson's algorithm for implementing mutual exclusion with only shared memory with strong hypotheses? I doubt that Java's memory model (or any other language modern enough to explicitly give a memory model) allows Peterson's algorithm to work... And if you are going to use explicit memory barriers, why not use synchronization instructions provided by the language?

Comment: @Pascal Cuoq I am not sure, can you point me to original paper on this algorithm, so I can check? What preconditions must be satisfied by the memory model semantics to ensure algorithm correctness? The reason for not using concurrency and synchronization mechanisms provided by Java is simply I am trying to understand Petersons algorithm, not concurrent programming in Java.

Comment: @Gabriel The algorithm is so short (the original article is famous for being only 2 pages) that it is entirely on the Wikipedia page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peterson%27s_algorithm . See the "Note" section too.

Comment: @Pascal Cuoq I read the article, but I could not find any mention of "strong hypotheses". So if I understood it correctly the problem being here is the possibility of reordering the memory accesses?

Comment: @Gabriel You're right, the problem is memory access reordering. The article predates the optimized implementations of multi-CPU / multi-core. The DEC Alpha designers were the first to weaken the idea of a single shared memory consistently viewed by all processors/cores/threads. This "single consistent shared memory" hypothesis is implicit (but clearly made) in the article.

Comment: @Pascal Cuoq ah, now I understand what you ment, thank you:)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

No one here has provided a correct/safe implementation of this algorithm in Java. I'm not sure how John W's solution is supposed to work since it's got pieces missing (namely the declarations of the ThreadLocals and an explanation of what is supposed to be in his array—primitive `booleans` don't have `get()` and `set()`).

[Chapter 17 of the Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/memory.html) explains the Java memory model. Of particular interest is [Section 17.4.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/memory.html#17.4.5), which describes the *happens-before* order. It's pretty easy to think about within a single thread. Consider the snippet:

```
int x, y, z, w;
x = 0;
y = 5;

z = x;
w = y;
```

Everyone will agree that at the end of this snippet, both `x` and `z` are equal to `0` and both `y` and `w` are equal to `5`. Ignoring the declarations, we have six actions here:

1. A write to `x`
2. A write to `y`
3. A read from `x`
4. A write to `z`
5. A read from `y`
6. A write to `w`

Because they all appear in the same thread, the JLS says that these reads and writes are guaranteed to exhibit this ordering: each action *n* above (because the actions are in a single thread) has a happens-before relationship with all actions *m*, *m* > *n*.

But what about different threads? **For normal field accesses, there are no happens-before relationships established between threads.** This means a Thread A could increment a shared variable and Thread B might read that variable but *not see the new value*. In the program's execution in the JVM, the propagation of Thread A's write may have been reordered to happen after Thread B's read.

In fact, Thread A could write to a variable `x`, and then to a variable `y`, establishing a happens-before relationship between those two actions within Thread A. But Thread B may read `x` and `y` and it is legal for B to get the new value of `y` **before** the new value of `x` appears. The spec says:

> More specifically, if two actions
>   share a happens-before relationship,
>   they do not necessarily have to appear
>   to have happened in that order to any
>   code with which they do not share a
>   happens-before relationship.

How do we fix this? For normal field accesses, the `volatile` keyword is enough:

> A write to a volatile variable
>   (§8.3.1.4)  v synchronizes-with all
>   subsequent reads of v by any thread
>   (where subsequent is defined according
>   to the synchronization order).

*synchronizes-with* is a stronger condition than happens-before, and since happens-before is transitive, if Thread A wants Thread B to see its writes to `x` and `y`, it just needs to write to a volatile variable `z` after writing `x` and `y`. Thread B needs to read from `z` before reading `x` and `y` and it will be guaranteed to see the new values of `x` and `y`.

In Gabriel's solution, we see this pattern: a write occurs to `in`, which would not be visible to other threads, but then a write occurs to `turn`, so other threads are guaranteed to see both writes as long as they read `turn` first.

Unfortunately, the while loop's conditional is backwards: to guarantee a thread does not see stale data for `in`, the while loop should read from `turn` first:

```
    // ...
    while (turn == other() && in[other()]) {
        // ...
```

With this fix in mind, most of the rest of the solution is ok: in the critical section, we don't care about staleness of data because, well, we're in the critical section! The only other flaw comes at the end: the Runnable sets `in[id]` to a new value and exits. Will the other Thread be guaranteed to see the new value of `in[id]`? The spec says no:

> The final action in a thread T1
>   synchronizes-with any action in
>   another thread T2 that detects that T1
>   has terminated. T2  may accomplish
>   this by calling T1.isAlive() or
>   T1.join().

So how do we fix it? Just add another write to `turn` at the end of the method:

```
    // ...
    in[id] = false;
    turn = other();
}
// ...
```

Since we reordered the while loop, the other thread will be guaranteed to see the new false value of `in[id]` because the write to `in[id]` happens-before the write to `turn` happens-before the read from `turn` happens-before the read from `in[id]`.

Needless to say, without a metric **ton** of comments, this method is brittle and someone could come along and change something and subtly break the correctness. Just declaring the array `volatile` is not good enough: as explained [in this thread](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/archive/1096.html) by Bill Pugh (one of the [lead researchers](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/) for the Java memory model), declaring an array `volatile` makes updates to the array *reference* visible to other threads. Updates to array elements are not necessarily visible (hence all the loops we just had to jump through by using another `volatile` variable to guard access to the array elements).

If you want your code to be clear and concise, keep it the way it is and change `in` to be an [AtomicIntegerArray](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicIntegerArray.html) (use 0 for false, 1 for true; there is no AtomicBooleanArray). This class acts like an array whose elements are all `volatile`, and so will solve all our problems nicely. Alternatively, you could just declare two volatile variables, `boolean in0` and `boolean in1`, and update them instead of using a boolean array.

Comment: Oh, thank you, this is probably the best answer I ever got on StackOverflow. This is very interesting and inspiring, I think I will look at some of the concurrent Java API.

Comment: Sometimes books are so good they pick up nicknames. The "PickAx Book", "K&R C", and the "Dinosaur Book" are a few. "The "Train Book" (http://www.javaconcurrencyinpractice.com/ ) is no exception. It covers the basics of the memory model and concurrency and then gets into the java.util.concurrent stuff in really good detail, while remaining eminently readable. If you want to learn more about the wonderful tools in java.util.concurrent, pick it up or borrow it from a friend.

Comment: This answer is fantastic.  Who on earth voted it down and why?  IMHO, it's rude to downvote without some form of comment.

Answer (score 5):

Unless you have some specific need for Peterson's agorithm (which would be strange when working in a high level language like Java), I suggest you take a look at the synchronization facilities built in to the language.

For example, you may find this book chapter on "Race Conditions and
Mutual Exclusion" in Java useful: http://java.sun.com/developer/Books/performance2/chap3.pdf

In particlar:

> Java provides built-in support
> awaiting this “change in state” via
> the notion of a condition. A condition
> is a bit of a misnomer, however,
> because it is entirely up to the user
> whether or not a condition actually
> occurred. Furthermore, a condition
> need not be specifically true or
> false. To use conditions, one must
> become familiar with three key methods
> of the Object class:
>
> • wait(): This
> method is used to await a condition.
> It is called when a lock is presently
> being held for a particular (shared)
> object.
>
> • notify(): This method is
> used to notify a single thread that a
> condition has (possibly) changed.
> Again, this method is called when a
> lock is presently being held for a
> particular object. Only a single
> thread can be awakened as a result of
> this call.
>
> • notifyAll(): This method
> is used to notify multiple threads
> that a condition has (possibly)
> changed. All threads that are running
> at the time this method is called will
> be notified.

Comment: As I mentioned in a comment to the question, this is specific to the algorithm, so you have not answered my question, however I appriaciate the effort and good quotes, thank you:)

Comment: People who are studying Computer Science need to know how a lock algorithm works without resourting to high-level language features. 
Classes like Distributed Computing or Operating System do require us to know how lock mechanism work, and we're often required to implement such algorithms in whatever language.

Answer (score 4):

I could not find one on the web myself, so I decided to try writing it:

```
public class Peterson implements Runnable {

    private static boolean[] in = { false, false };
    private static volatile int turn = -1;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Thread(new Peterson(0), "Thread - 0").start();
        new Thread(new Peterson(1), "Thread - 1").start();
    }

    private final int id;

    public Peterson(int i) {
        id = i;
    }

    private int other() {
        return id == 0 ? 1 : 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        in[id] = true;
        turn = other();
        while (in[other()] && turn == other()) {
            System.out.println("[" + id + "] - Waiting...");
        }
        System.out.println("[" + id + "] - Working ("
                + ((!in[other()]) ? "other done" : "my turn") + ")");
        in[id] = false;
    }
}
```

Feel free to comment, it will be appreciated:)

Comment: You'll want to check out the relevant sections in the Java memory model (http://is.gd/cpKfw ). Writes to array elements do not establish any sort of happens-before relationship, so there is no guarantee that Thread1 will see Thread0 setting in[0] to true. It doesn't even work with volatile (http://is.gd/cpKpY ). Perhaps try rewriting this using an AtomicIntegerArray as in (http://is.gd/cpKrf ), using 0 and 1 instead of true and false.

Answer (score 3):

You should really check out the book The Art of Multiprocessor Programming.  He in great detail goes over different lock implementations (both spin, and blocking).  He also goes over different other types of concurrent algorithms (skip list for instance).  Here is a snippet from his book on the Peterson Lock algorithm

```
Class Peterson implements Lock{
   private final boolean []flag = new boolean[2];
   private volatile int victim;

   public void lock(){
        int i = ThreadID.get(); // ThreadID is a ThreadLocal field
        int j= 1 - i;
        flag[i] = true;    // I'm Interested
        victim = i;        // You go first
        while(flag[j] && victim == i){}; //wait
   }
   public void unlock(){
       int i = ThreadID.get();
       flag[i] = false;      //Not interested anymore
   }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for a suggestion. Is this different in any way from what I posted?

Comment: I dont see any true difference other then the Lock implementation.  Yours looks correct, I was posting this to show as a Lock and point out the good reference of the book I suggested

Comment: W I understand, thank you, I am glad to get it right, although as stated in comments to the question, the compiler violates important preconditions, which makes this algorithm uncorrect for Javas memory model semantics.

Answer (score 0):

While not the paterson algo, the AtomicBoolean and Atomic* classes use the approach of lockless, busy loops to update shared data.  They may suit your requirements.