# Implementation of Peterson's solution doesn't work properly

Tags: java, multithreading, algorithm

My school gived an implementation of Peterson’s solution. I have some problems about it.
You can find the whole code at the end.

Firsly; Is it correct that the both threads(AddOne and SubOne) enter and leave the critical region with the same process value '0'.

```
PetersonsSolution.enter_region(0); //Both use 0 as paramater.
```

The output of the code is like that:

```
++ finihed
-- finished
Result: 0
++ finihed
-- finished
Result: -49
-- finished
++ finihed
Result: -64
++ finihed
-- finished
Result: -54
...ans so on
```

I think if Peterson's Solution work as expected the results must be equal to 0. But they are all different.

So I change the class AddOne like this: Give a different parameter.

```
class AddOne extends Thread {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {

            PetersonsSolution.enter_region(1); //give 1 as paramater.
            PetersonsSolution.myValue++;
            PetersonsSolution.leave_region(1); //give 1 as paramater.

        }
        System.out.println("++ finihed");
    }

}
```

This gives me the result i expected:

```
-- finished
++ finihed
Result: 0
++ finihed
-- finished
Result: 0
```

But this time, after one or two seconds the program enter an infinite loop and print nothing to screen. I think it stuck in this `while(turn == process && interested[other])`

My  questions are;

1. Is it correct to give different process parameters to get the
   expected result(Result: 0)?
2. If it is correct why it stuck after some time?

Thank you all!

Peterson's Solution Implementation:

```
public class PetersonsSolution {

    static int myValue = 0;
    static int turn;
    static boolean interested[] = {false, false};

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        while (true) {

            AddOne add = new AddOne();
            SubOne sub = new SubOne();

            add.start();
            sub.start();

            add.join();
            sub.join();

            System.out.println("Result: " + myValue);
        }
    }

    public static void enter_region(int process){
        int other;
        other = 1 - process;
        interested[process] = true;
        turn = process;

        while(turn == process && interested[other]){
            //System.out.println("waiting");
        }
    }

    public static void leave_region(int process){
        interested[process] = false;
    }

}

class AddOne extends Thread {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {

            PetersonsSolution.enter_region(0);
            PetersonsSolution.myValue++;
            PetersonsSolution.leave_region(0);

        }
        System.out.println("++ finihed");
    }

}

class SubOne extends Thread {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {

            PetersonsSolution.enter_region(0);
            PetersonsSolution.myValue--;
            PetersonsSolution.leave_region(0);

        }
        System.out.println("-- finished");
    }
}
```

Comment: You have shared data in your code but you do not use any syncronization. It doesn't seem good.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2911915/peterson-algorithm-in-java

Answer (score -1):

If two threads access shared state, and at least one modifies this shared state, you need synchronization. Your code doesn't have any synchronization, and the output is thus indeterministic.

Read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html, and/or read Java Concurrency in Practice, by Brian Goetz.